# Sending automated emails from Firebase through Google Cloud Platform (no third parties)

Tags: email, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We've been doing some research for many hours already.

The first solution that appears everywhere (other StackExchange questions too) is using third-party service *SendGrid.com* and sometimes in conjunction with Zapier, but that's not the approach we are wanting to implement.

For sending without third-parties in the middle, the first solution that seemed viable was "Firebase Triggers", which was anounced on Google I/O 2014 but never came to life and [seemingly was merged into Google Cloud Functions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/GEsLy3S85QY/8htLM3QxFgAJ) which is still in Alpha.

I'm pretty sure I had seen the solution almost a year ago in a link on the FireBase blog, but [the only post that seems to have existed upon that matter is now empty](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/email-notifications-with-firebase_90.html).

We've never worked before with GCP, but our logic tells us this matter should be solved (inside Google) using with another GCP existing API, and the [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail/sending-receiving-with-mail-api) is apparently the correct one, but there seems not to be any way our Firebase Web App could make the request.

Could anyone (preferably with GCP experience) please explain what's the situation here, and how does Google expects it's FireBase developers to send emails to their clients?

Comment: For an up to date version of that blog post, see: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Comment: Firebase has no built-in support for sending developer-specified email. In that sense it also has no expectation on how an app sends email to its users. One way to do so would be through app engine as shown in the blog post you mentioned. But there are many more ways to accomplish the same.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, we are developing a WebApp, so... we would appreciate such a link for a WebApp approach if it exists...

Comment: @davidtaubmann Actually you can follow the tutorial shared by FrankvanPuffelen by starting at "Adding backend logic using App Engine". You create a project in Android Studio but you just work in the AppEngine module part, i.e. you leave "untouched" the Android app module.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen and 3371862, as I understand the link mentioned, the procedure makes an inquiry to app engine from the app itself, not from firebase, which means that in Web Apps environment, the inquiry for the email would be made by the client-browser directly to app engine... Wouldn't that be a huge security risk? And if not... Please explain why not...

Comment: @davidtaubmann The link shows how to configure and develop a servlet in App Engine that connects to the Firebase database and installs a listener: when the listener is triggered the servlet sends a mail. The servlet is normally called through a cron job configured in the App Engine project. There is a possibility to call the servlet from a browser through the servlet URL, but this should only be used for testing. However it could indeed be called by someone else (knowing the url), and I am not sure at this moment if we can secure it, I have to dive into the doc. To be cont.

Comment: continued... My point with my comment above (on 6 march) was to indicate that the listener is triggered when data is added/modified to the Firebase db independently of the type of front-end which added/modified the data (an Android app, a web app or even the Firebase console). So in other words it perfectly works for your case with a WebApp.

Comment: @davidtaubmann Yes you can secure the cron job, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#securing_urls_for_cron

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Firebase Functions

As gracefully stated by @ajostergaard, TODAY Google has [announced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/introducing-cloud-functions-for-firebase.html) its much waited **[Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)**, but precisely for Firebase they've implemented their own specific [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) which substitutes the [Triggers shown in conferences since Nov. 2014](https://youtu.be/aCK_1sq6Dl0?t=4h44m2s) (more than 2 years ago!) and [mentioned in Firebase groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/GEsLy3S85QY) .

This is an example link that explains exactly how to do what is asked in this question:

- [Sending emails from Firebase (FINALLY! and just in time for our WebApp)](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users)

Comment: My answer got deleted by a very 'nice' moderator because I apparently tried to spread the good news too eagerly. Apparently instead of answering your question I should have marked it as duplicate and pointed it to another older 'duplicate' question with lots of wrong and out of date answers on it. Sometimes I wonder! :)

Comment: @ajostergaard , could you please direct me to the other question you mentioned in the comment?

Comment: There are many to which my answer was appropriate, not necessarily duplicates. Some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723195/is-there-any-way-to-do-email-confirmation-for-firebase-user-creation-and-or-pass/42706591 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180768/send-email-from-android-using-firebase/42704008 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656191/send-email-when-match-in-firebase-database/28656376

Comment: Does this also work with non-Firebase Google Cloud Functions?