# Angular - Send email from the Contact Form

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sendgrid

I have created a simple Contact Form in my Angular5 app. The content is stored in Firestore. Fine.

But now I want to add a new feature : when the user submit the Contact Form, I'd like to receive an email with the form content. The content is basic (only text).

I try some cases with Sendgrid, Firebase functions,... Without success.

[Sending automated emails from Firebase through Google Cloud Platform (no third parties)](http://Sending%20automated%20emails%20from%20Firebase%20through%20Google%20Cloud%20Platform%20(no%20third%20parties)) sends an automatic email (stored in index.js) for new firebase authentication.

But in my case, I want to trigger the mail (index.js) from an angular component (the Contact Form).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending automated emails from Firebase through Google Cloud Platform (no third parties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616809/sending-automated-emails-from-firebase-through-google-cloud-platform-no-third-p)

Comment: You can't send an email from a web client, it needs to come from a server of some kind. Choose a service or write a backend service of your own and use it