# Send confirmation email using Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-confirmation

I want to send confirmation email when user registers in iOS application.

I have searched a lot. I find only verification using Firebase. But can we do confirmation email using Firebase.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Anyway, take a look at this other similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616809/sending-automated-emails-from-firebase-through-google-cloud-platform-no-third-p

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication does not have a built-in option to send a confirmation email. If you need this functionality, you will have to build it yourself.

There is a great [example of how to send a welcome email in the `function-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/quickstarts/email-users).